# How do I blend textures of joined objects?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I'm trying to make an ammo pick up. But as on the picture, the bullets and the bullet caps are separated by the line where they join.
I'm still new to blender, is there a way to merge them together into a single texture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add an image of the wireframe, that would be helpful.

The short answer is that you'll need to make the mesh for the bullet (top) and the casing (bottom) connected. Once you do that, there will be a less noticeable seam.

That having been said, normal ammunition has a very distinct seam between the bullet and the casing. If you make the bullet orange-ish and the casing yellow-ish, it'll look like a real bullet.

If that's not what you're after, then you should explore how to model the bullet and the casing together as one mesh. One approach might be to delete the bottom half of the spherical bullet (the part that I'm assuming is hidden inside the casing). Then extrude the bottom ring downward into a cylinder. Then close the cylinder at the bottom. This will result in a bullet and casing that are one piece, and might make your texturing job easier.

Comment: Uploaded an image of the wireframe.
The bullet is already a semi sphere.
I exported the model to unity and put a mat on it and it actually looks better that way, still, I'll look into your advice just for myself so I know how to do it in the future. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, you're already half-way there. The only thing you'd need to do is find "remove doubles" and it'll merge those vertices that are REALLY close to each other, so that the bullet and cylinder become connected.

Comment: The other thing that you already started to figure out, is that if the material/shader is actually identical on both, there will be almost no visible seam anyway.

Comment: "remove doubles" is now "merge by distance" in v2.81.16 but it did the magic